# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview, android-cardview

I am trying to add an ImageView into a CardView widget but when i go to open the activity that contains my cardview the app crashes and I get this error message in my logcat

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class ImageView
```

I've seen other people have had this problem and the solution was to reduce the size of the image itself contained in the drawable folder I am now using an image with a size of 295x197px is this still too big?

Here is my cardview xml file the cardview i am working on is the first one in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.brian.barter2.furniture"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_furniture"
android:background="#efefef">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/furniture_img1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="Product"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
04-13 20:25:23.930 32498-32498/com.example.brian.barter2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brian.barter2/com.example.brian.barter2.furniture}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                           at com.example.brian.barter2.furniture.onCreate(furniture.java:25)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02004d a=-1 r=0x7f02004d}
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1892)
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                           at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                           at com.example.brian.barter2.furniture.onCreate(furniture.java:25) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

04-13 20:25:25.234 32498-32498/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32498 SIG: 9

Any input would be greatly appreciate thanks.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Theres the stack trace

Comment: The Stacktrace says Caused by:`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02004d a=-1 r=0x7f02004d}` Please provide more information about the drawable. It seems corrupt.

Comment: The image is a jpg and i pasted it in from my computer

Comment: When i added the image into the mipmap directory it work fine still don't understand why drawable didn't work

Comment: add       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
in gradle